# Azure MobileServices on Android returns "The id must be numeric" on updates

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am programming an android program where links to my Azure with MobileService on Android.'
During execution of a similar update statement which can be found [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/how-to-guides/work-with-android-client-library/#updating), it returns as error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The id must be numeric".

I am using the follow codes:

```
mTable.update(item, new TableOperationCallback<EntityTest>() {
    public void onCompleted(EntityTest result,
    Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
       if (exception == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception+"///"+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
});
```

Any help is gladly and hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not completely positive but Mobile Services recently changed over to a new model for the ID column on tables (it use to be integer based but is now String based).   I would guess you're using an old version of the SDK which assumes it's going to get back integers for the ID column when now it will return strings.  I would suggest downloading the latest version of the SDK and making sure your data model class (EntityTest from the looks of your code) is expecting a String ID and not an int.

Comment: Chris is correct - there was a change about a week ago - see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/f020a4e2-9301-4318-9023-3a1668959221 for more details. The latest SDK (you can download it at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/?sdk=mobile) has support for the new tables with string ids.

Comment: Yup, you guys are correct!! I am using v1.01 of the SDK which does not  support String ID but recently changed my Database to String ID. Updating it solved the problem!! :)